# C: is `fgets` effective when the buffer size passed to it is smaller than user input?

Tags: c, stdin, fgets

Suppose the declaration is

```
char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);
```

Then from the manual, `fgets` reads in *atmost* `size` - 1 bytes from the `stream`. I have read that `fgets` is considered safe when reading in user input from `stream`= `stdin` because (among other reasons) it reads in the newline character itself as opposed to `scanf` which does not, which I know causes the problem of the newline being read the next time `scanf` is called instead of the actual user input, right ?

But shouldn't this advantage only hold when `size` - 1 >= no of bytes entered by the  user ? As an example, suppose the user types in the following

```
Hello World!\n
```

The newline is them pressing the return key, so they type in 13 bytes in total. So the buffer that can accomodate this should be at least 14 bytes long, right ? But suppose it is not, suppose it is just 13 (it could even be less):

```
char buf[13];
```

So only the first 12 bytes should be read into `buf`:

```
1 2 3 4 5  6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
H e l l o    W o r l  d  !  \n
✓ ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓  ✓  ✓  ✕    ( ✓ read  ✕ not read )
```

So shouldnt the `\n` be left behind in `stdin` and become the first character read the next time `fgets` is called ? Should things get "worse" when `buf` is made even smaller, with other characters like `!` `\n` being left behind if `size` = 12  ?

Is it at all possible to remove these characters from `stdin`, because I have read that calling `fflush (stdin)` has undefined behaviour and have never used it.

Any help/resource is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Yes, anything not read remains in the input buffer: nothing is discarded. Just use a buffer that is large enough to hold the expected input. Be generous rather than trying to define a size that is *just* big enough. If the buffer might not be large enough, start by obtaining it with memory allocation, and reallocate it when too small (see previous questions). You know when it is too small because there is no newline retained.

Comment: That makes sense - so shouldn't `getline` always be prefered ?

Comment: That is a non-standard function. You could write your own if you wanted one and it isn't in the implementation's library.

Comment: If you are compiling POSIX compatible code at `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` of  `200809L` minimum, then yes, you can use [`getline`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html). It is *not* part of the standard library (yet), but *is* provided by POSIX implementations meeting or exceeding that version.

Comment: @WhozCraig that was helpful thanks, but additionally I have read that `getline` uses `realloc` calls internally which is why, correct me if I am wrong, it might be less efficient, time-wise  ?

Comment: What you do with the string buffer after each `getline` is up to you. It will only `realloc` when it needs to (and you can certainly force that to always if you like, but...). At the risk of appearing self-gratifying, [see this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66664670/1322972), and specifically the *second* code example, which shows how to cycle `getline` calls and buffer reuse whilst making copies of the actual line data desired for retention.

Comment: Certainly it is possible to remove the characters that were "left behind".  Just read them!  `while( (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' ) ;`

Comment: The other downside of `getline` is that if the user can input arbitrarily long lines, they can cause your program to consume arbitrarily large amounts of memory.